# easy way to merge rows in 2D array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a 2D array[,], and I want to set the array[0] row to be equal to the array[1] row.

Originally I thought array[0] = array[1] would set all row 0 variables to be equal to row 1 variables. But it didn't work.

so I tried this,

```
for (int i = 0; i < itemList.Length; i++)
{
    itemList [0,i] = itemList [1,i];
}
```

but it gets "out of range" errors.

I feel like I'm missing a very elegant way of doing this, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try itemList[0].Length in your for statement.

Comment: You can have two types of two dimensional arrays [,] and [][].  Make sure you are using correct type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, the loop will go out of bounds.

For a 2D array, `itemList.Length = number of rows * number of columns`

You can try out the following:

```
int rowLength = itemList.GetLength(0);
int colLength = itemList.GetLength(1);
for (int j = 0; j < colLength; j++)
{
    itemList[0, j] = itemList[1, j];
}
```

Check by printing out the values:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rowLength; i++)
{
     for (int j = 0; j < colLength; j++)
     {
         Console.Write(string.Format("{0} ", itemList[i, j]));
     }
     Console.Write(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Hope this helps!!!

[Assumed that itemList contains `int` values]

Comment: Thats perfect, thank you, i didn't know 2D array length was measured like that.

Answer (score 1):

Try itemList.GetLength(0) to get first item count and 
itemList.GetLength(1) for second item count in a 2D array.

Modify your code like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < itemList.GetLength(1); i++) {
      itemList [0,i] = itemList [1,i]; 
     }
```